# Python's threading.local() isn't working for me

Tags: python, multithreading

This is pretty simple:

```
import threading as t
t.local().x = 1
print t.local().x
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\e272nk\Desktop\tst.py", line 3, in <module>
    print t.local().x
AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'x'
```

The attribute assignment seems to be working ok, why can't I retrieve the value?

This is Python v2.7.5 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating an instance of the class `local`, setting an attribute on it, then discarding it. Then in the next line, you are creating *another* instance of `local` and trying to print a certain attribute from it. Since you didn't set the attribute on that instance, it doesn't have it, and you get an error.

[As shown in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local), you should be creating an instance of `local` and keeping it around:

```
import threading as t

locs = t.local()
locs.x = 1
print locs.x
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and just creating a new instance of any class, and assigning dynamic properties on it at runtime? I mean, what's so special about the object that `t.local()` returns in terms of threading?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: The difference is that a thread-local has different values on each thread _even if it's a global or explicitly shared variable_. If there's a more readable way to give each thread a separate instance in the first place and avoid sharing, you don't need thread-locals. (Also: if you don't know _why_ you want thread-locals, you probably don't want them.)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: See [this code](http://pastebin.com/YRVims6E) for a trivial example. Even though `tl` is global, and `threadfunc` sets it to `1`, the main thread still sees `0`.

Comment: Attributes on an instance of `t.local()` are guaranteed to be thread-local. Behind the scenes, it's figuring out what thread it's being accessed from and storing each thread's attributes separately. For more info and examples: `import _threading_local; help(_threading_local)`

Comment: Obviously I'm new at Python's threading.  :)  For some reason, I was thinking that t.local() was a function that, within a single thread, always returned the same object, sort of like globals() does.  Thanks!